# How to align top/bottom hight of an UITableView in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, uitableview, vertical-alignment

I have a grouped style UITableView. It have only one section & the section has only 5 rows always (Fixed). The section is shown like..

[image]

But I want to show it in the middle of the screen like this...

[image]

What should I do to get this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you can set the edge insets, but you should not do that.

This is not a behavior that user would expect.

But if you reallllllllly want to you can user the edgeInset via the interface builder or via code:

```
self.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(200.0f, 0.f, 0.f, 0.f);
```

You will have to figure out the top of the offset. (this is the 200.0f number)

Comment: Thanks for your reply.. It shows an error message as "Property 'edgeInsets' not found on object of type 'UITableView *'

Comment: Thank you so much.. It works fine. A small correction is, one 'f' is wrongly put in 200f.0f, the correct number is 200.0f. Will apple reject my app if I center-align the table section?

Comment: No I don't think they will, but it not what user will expect.

Comment: Thank you for your valuable suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I have a class that extends UIViewController and i found that adding the following (swift, xcode 6.1) seems to move the tableView to top

self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false